# Tomcat is failing to load tag library tld files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm running an old tomcat application and I can't get it to start up.  I keep getting errors like this

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [null] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN], system ID [http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] and base URI [file:/C:/Users/OITLasGardnM/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/mds_web_app_java/WEB-INF/report-engine/tlds/birt.tld] to a known, local entity.

I've checked the file path. The file exists and does not appear to be locked by any other process.  Can you help me understand why the build process is looking here for this file and why it's failing to find it?

I'm using

- java 1.8
- tomcat 9

edit: I've added the following to my web.xml

```html
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://www.eclipse.org/birt/taglibs/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/report-engine/tlds/birt.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
```

Comment: You may have to specify the location of the TLD file in the web.xml configuration file. The xml tag `<jsp-config>` has a sub-tag `</taglib-location>` (verify the documentation for exact tag names and usage).

Comment: How did you know that the file is not locked?

Comment: I opened the file from the command line in pico.

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old tags that were used for JSP 1.2 spec. Tomcat 9 doesn't work with tags under that spec. So, the DTD `web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd` doesn't work with Tomcat 9.

It requires JSP 2.3 spec.

Also Tomcat 4.1 supports the old spec., so you can run it on the old server.